# Convertir Texto en Codigo de barras C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp

Quiero convertir una cadena de texto digitada en un `TextBox` a código de barras,  pero presentó un error:

```
Error: No se puede convertir implicitamente el tipo 'System.Drawing.image' en 'String'
```

empleo la siguiente instrucción:

librerias:

```
using BarcodeLib;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;


   protected void ButtonGenereBarra_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)

     {
      BarcodeLib.Barcode Codigobar = new BarcodeLib.Barcode();
      Codigobar.IncludeLabel = true;
      panelResult.BackImageUrl = Codigobar.Encode(BarcodeLib.TYPE.CODE128, TextBoxLeerSerial.Text, Color.Black, Color.White, 400, 100);
     }
```

alguna idea de como puedo hacerlo o en que puedo estar fallando?

Comment: Te sugiero agregar la declaración de la variable Codigobar, si estás usando librerías externas también incluyelas para tener un contexto completo.

Comment: Gracias, ya edite la pregunta

Comment: panelResult.BackImageUrl  espera recibir una url, y vos le estas pasando una imagen. cual era tu idea?

Comment: estaba intentando convertir lo que hay en el textbox en codigo de barras y mostrarlo en un panel, tambien use la propiedad `backgroundimage` pero la liberia `windows.forms` me Genera error.

Comment: si si. no podes usar windows.form en asp.. tenes que usar los controles propios de asp o html. y con un image no probaste?

Comment: lo he intentado de esta forma `Image1.image = Codigobar.Encode(BarcodeLib.TYPE.CODE128, TextBoxLeerSerial.Text, Color.Black, Color.White, Width: 400, Height: 100);` y aun no lo he logrado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba así, lo que hago es asignarle la imagen a un stream y luego convertir eso a una imagen base64

```
System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
BarcodeLib.Barcode Codigobar = new BarcodeLib.Barcode();
Codigobar.IncludeLabel = true;
System.Drawing.Image img = Codigobar.Encode(BarcodeLib.TYPE.CODE128, TextBoxLeerSerial.Text, Color.Black, Color.White, 400, 100);
img.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
panelResult.BackImageUrl = "data:image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(stream.ToArray(), 0, stream.ToArray().Length);
```

Comment: Gracias @Victor, me ha sido de mucha utilidad.

Comment: De nada bro, lo hice investigando y a ojo no pude probarlo espero te sirva.

Comment: Me ha sido de gran utilidad

Answer (score 1):

Si estas generando una imagen debes mostrarla en un `PictureBox` no en un `Panel`, usa los controles correctos para cada caso

```
PictureBox1.Image = Codigobar.Encode(BarcodeLib.TYPE.CODE128, ...
```

de esta forma se muestra la imagen que genere el codigo

Esta claro por la propiedad `BackImageUrl` una url es un string por eso dice `Url`

Comment: Hola @LeandroTuttini PictureBox, es un control para Windows Forms y yo estoy desarrollando es un web forms.

Comment: disculpa no vi los tags pense que era winform al usar un panel